# Where do the ahadith in Riyad As-Saliheen come from, and what grade are they?

Tags: hadith, books

I always understood Riyad As-Saliheen (the famous book compilation of hadith) to contain *ahadith from Saheeh Bukhari or Saheeh Muslim, or both.* But when [perusing it on sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/), I noticed [one hadith says at the end](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/18#116):

> [Abu Dawud and At- Tirmidhi].

What exactly is Riyad As-Saliheen? Where do the ahadith come from? What range are they (eg. is it a collection of only saheeh, or does it also contain hassan, da'eef, and mawdoo' ahadith?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you mentioned, [Riyad-us-Saliheen](http://abdurrahman.org/seerah/riyad/index.html) is compilation of hadiths by Imam An-Nawawi, a great scholar of Hadith and fiqh. He is known for such compilations like [40 Hadeeth by An-Nawawi](http://abdurrahman.org/sunnah/nawavi40explanation.html), [40 Hadith Qudsi](http://abdurrahman.org/sunnah/40hadithqudsi.html) etc. Riyad-us-Saliheen is a popular and useful compilation because of its classification based on wide range of topics. It serves as a hadith primer. It has selected hadiths of approximately 2000 hadiths from the six major collections: Bukhari, Muslim, Abu Dawood, Tirmidhi, An-Nasa'i and Ibn Majah. These 2000 hadiths are grouped in 372 Chapters and 19 Sections with titles - *The Book of Good Manners, The Book about the Etiquette of Eating, The Book of Dress, The Book of the Etiquette of Sleeping, Lying and Sitting, etc* and so on. Hence, it serves as an easy reader.

Since the hadiths compiled are from the six major collections, it can be *considered* or *called* as authentic. However, it is not devoid of weak hadiths. There are some [hadiths checked and declared weak](http://abdurrahman.org/sunnah/daefriyadh.html) by Shaykh Al-Albaani